# Can pop a element from a list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

In below code I want to pop an element from guessList. Is it possible? Is List in Kotlin Mutable?

```
fun String.getAllCorrectLetters(guess: String): Int{
    var count = 0
    val guessList = guess.toList()
    for((index1,ch1) in this.withIndex()){
        for (element in guessList) {
            if (ch1 == element){
                count++
                // Can I remove element from guessList here
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Anybody knows how to do this in Kotlin? If can't, can anybody suggest a better way?

Comment: `pop()`  is a function for `Stack` types of data structure. Whereas `guessList` is a `List`.

Comment: Also, that could be simplified a lot, e.g. by making `guessList` a `MutableList` and using `remove()` instead of the inner loop.  (Unfortunately, `removeAll()` doesn't return a count, else you could replace the outer loop too.)